# Windows .BAT to move all directories matching mask from dir A to dir B

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a .BAT file to move all sub-directories (whose name matches a mask) of C:\WINNT\Temp to H:\SOMEOTHERPLACE.

So if my mask is ABC* then the directories :

```
C:\WINNT\Temp\ABC1
C:\WINNT\Temp\ABC2
C:\WINNT\Temp\ABC3
```

should be moved to

```
H:\SOMEOTHERPLACE
```

and everything else (including files, as opposed to directories, which match the mask) should not. I do want to move them and not copy.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Maybe this is clear already but by 'move sub-directories' I mean move the sub-directories and all their contents

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK I've figured this out. If you write a movedirs.bat file containing the single line

```
for /d %%X in (%1) do move %%X %2\%%~nX
```

And then run it (with argument 1 being the mask for the directories I want to move and argument 2 being the directory I wish to move the directories to) as

```
C:\>movedirs.bat C:\WINNT\Temp\ABC* H:\SOMEOTHERPLACE\
```

It produces the effect I want.

The /d argument on the 'for' ensures that only directories are processed. The '~n' modifier on the %%X variable means that the original sub-directory name (as opposed to the entire path) is used as the target within the second command line argument.

Just for the sake of posterity in investigating this I did something similar with xcopy but then i would have had to get involved in deleting the source so for my purposes move works better but for the record here's the same idea wrapped around xcopy.

```
for /d %%X in (%1) do xcopy %%X %2\%%~nX /E /I
```

To process directories with as well as without extensions, for example "C:\MyDir*.MyExt" above command will need a combined (filename+extension) modifier "~nx":

```
for /d %%W in (%1) do xcopy %%W %2\%%~nxW /E /F /R /Y /I
```

Answer (score 0):

[Comments are useless for structured answers so I'll repeat the comment here - with a couple of edits !]

Thanks for your answer but I've found that you can't use xcopy with a wildcard on the source. Or rather you can use wildcards but then you get only the directories being created without any content. So if you do this ...

```
H:\SOMEOTHERPLACE>xcopy C:\WINNT\Temp\ABC1 /E
```

... you'll get the the ABC1 directory copied to your current directory as you might reasonably expect but if you do this ...

```
H:\SOMEOTHERPLACE>xcopy C:\WINNT\Temp\ABC* /E
```

... you'll get each directory name present in C:\WINNT\Temp appearing in your current directory but those directories will be empty ! Please tell me I'm wrong but that's what I find !